# Xpath count function dosn't work

Tags: xml, xpath, count

I have the following Xml document :

```
 <root>
<lockerEntries>
    <accountId>
      <accountId>717</accountId>
      <businessUnit>USIT</businessUnit>
    </accountId>
    <policyId>ps_d8d</policyId>
    <id>0X02A9C2A2E59145DAFF482</id>
    <lastModified>1448265403925</lastModified>
    <authorizationStart>1448265403453</authorizationStart>
    <lockerEntryEvents>
      <created>1483452726419</created>
      <name>102</name>
    </lockerEntryEvents>
    <lockerEntryEvents>
      <created>1483452726419</created>
      <name>102</name>
    </lockerEntryEvents>
    <lockerEntryEvents>
      <created>1483452726419</created>
      <name>102</name>
    </lockerEntryEvents>
    <lockerEntryEvents>
      <created>1483452726419</created>
      <name>102</name>
    </lockerEntryEvents>
  </lockerEntries>
<lockerEntries>
    <accountId>
      <accountId>71713470</accountId>
      <businessUnit>USIT</businessUnit>
    </accountId>
    <policyId>ps_010fe850</policyId>
    <id>0X0000014FB321985CB7AD7E9CEC19E79</id>
    <lastModified>1441820147278</lastModified>
    <authorizationStart>1441820145385</authorizationStart>
    <lockerEntryEvents>
      <created>23332345362</created>
      <name>QUEUED</name>
    </lockerEntryEvents>
  </lockerEntries>
</root>
```

How to write an XPath expression to select count of lockerEntryEvents what are under lockerEntries and where policyId=ps_d8d
I tried 
`(//lockerEntries[policyId="ps_d8d"]//count(//lockerEntryEvents))` but it doesn't work. It should be count=4 now
Thank You

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> *"How to write an XPath expression to select count of `lockerEntryEvents` what are under `lockerEntries` and where `policyId=ps_d8d`"*

This is the correct XPath :

```
count(//lockerEntries[policyId='ps_d8d']/lockerEntryEvents)
```

**<kbd>[`xpathtester demo`](http://www.xpathtester.com/xpath/47a266a85620a02b264eb05a7476acb9)</kbd>**

**output :**

```
4
```